# checkbox is not set checked onclick in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 3 html checkboxes (`<input type="checkbox" id="chkBillTos" class="chk" />`) with same class and different Id where i want toggle between them(i.e If one checked other two's unchecked). But when i clicked on one check box ,its not checked while other two can be checked or unchecked on that time.

```js
$(".chk").click(function() {
  $('.chk').attr('checked', 'checked');
  //$('.chk').attr('unchecked', 'unchecked');
  var id = $(this.id);
  id.checked = true;
  $(id).attr('checked', 'checked');
  if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    alert($(this));
    $(this).is(':checked') = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you only want one of these three checkboxes to be checked at any one time then you're making this *much* harder than it needs to be; just use a radio input. Then you don't need any JS at all.

Comment: No, my requirement on checkbox basis because by default no one checkbox is checked.

Comment: You can still do that with radios: http://jsfiddle.net/dozsfegu/

Comment: But its client requirement to using toggles checkbox.

Comment: Then educate your client why that's a stupid idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rory McCrossan already stated, radio buttons might suite you much better (no JS needed).

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="a"> 1</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="a"> 2</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="a"> 3</label>
```

If you still want to use checkboxes, here is how you can:

```js
$('.check').on('change', function () {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $('.check').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label><input type="checkbox" class="check"> 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="check"> 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="check"> 3</label>
```

Instead of using `$.attr()`, I use `$.prop()` to get/set checked state.

Comment: This seems to be buggy if you click the selected checkbox twice it seems.

Answer (score 0):

This will uncheck all checkboxes except current one:

```
$(".chk").click(function() {
  $('.chk').not('#'+this.id).prop('checked', false);
});
```